# Upload e recuperação de uma imagem com Angular

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, rest, file-upload

Vamos supor que tenho um formulário de cadastro de usuário aonde quero salvar uma foto do mesmo. Envio esses dados por `POST` para o servidor(Java) aonde faço a inclusão no banco de dados.

Qual a melhor maneira (prática) de enviar essa foto junto com os outros dados para o meu servidor? Salvo essa imagem em um diretório ou em um campo `BLOB` no banco de dados? Tenho que enviar a imagem como um `Array` de `bytes`? E como consigo recuperar essa imagem quando fizer uma consulta no meu banco?

Se possível gostaria de alguns exemplos ou explicações.

Comment: Para salvar no servidor, a melhor opção é salvar a imagem no disco e somente o caminho dela no banco de dados. Para recuperar a imagem seria pegar o caminho no banco de dados e fazer uma requisição no caminho da imagem *(Ex: my.server.com/imagens/imagem.png)*

Comment: Entendi, e como faço o upload pro servidor?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso de duas formas: **1** - fazendo upload da imagem no servidor e salvando o link ou referência no banco de dados. **2** - criando um rash de base64 da imagem e salvando no banco.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo gerando rash: https://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está usando AngularJS vou indicar um plugin javascript para o mesmo.

É o [FlowJS (ng-flow)](http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/). Um exemplo:

```
<div flow-init="{target: '/upload'}"
     flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"
     flow-file-success="$file.msg = $message">

  <input type="file" flow-btn/>
      Input OR Other element as upload button
  <span class="btn" flow-btn>Upload File</span>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.msg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Na parte do JS como ficaria?

Comment: Aqui tem um dos exemplos: https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/tree/master/samples/basic